# How to get the URI in the component using React Navigation via deep linking?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have used React Navigation to open a component via deep linking. How do I get the URI which was called in the component and the parameters?

For example, my URI is `mychat://chat/Eric`. How do I get this Uri and the parameter `Eric` in my React Component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no URIs. React Navigation simply uses route keys to determine which component to display. Check out the [Screen Tracking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/screen-tracking.html) guide from the official react navigation docs.

I personally use the `onNavigationStateChange` prop on my top level navigator and track screens that way.

Edit:

According to the [deep linking documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html) any of the query string params, such as `chat/:user` gets passed in as a param. So you'll be able to call

```
navigation.getParam('user')
```

Comment: For example, my URI is `mychat://chat/Eric`. Is there no way I can get this Uri and the parameter `Eric` in my React Component?

Comment: @khateeb I think you misunderstand what react navigation is. It does not tell you anything to do with URIs. It's used for navigating between components not actual protocols such as HTTP

Comment: Oh damn. My mistake. I forgot to mention I was using it for deep linking.

Comment: And the full URI?

Comment: @khateeb why would you need the full URI. Surely you just need to know which user or channel is being viewed? Which you can do based on the component?

Comment: @khateeb Were you able to find a way to use "Eric" in your component?

Comment: @Dexter there are plenty of valid reasons to want a whole URL. Please don't assume that simplified examples (as required of SO) include full context.